# Draw text over image using canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview

I'm facing an issue using the canvas component on Android, I'd like to draw a text over an image at the same position of the textview.
I'm using a draggable textview as a demonstration of the entered text, so the user could see what it looks like before generating the image.

You could see a screenshot of my canvas drawing here:

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFU8g.png)

And here the code used to generate the new image

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
tp.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
tp.setTextSize(mText.getTextSize());

String text = mTextView.getText().toString();
int textWidth = (int) tp.measureText(text, 0, text.length());

canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0,0, null);
canvas.drawText(text, mTextView.getX(), mTextView.getY(), tp);
```

How could I fix this ?

Comment: Well, the getX and getY functions get the X and Y relative to the parent view, which may not be the right values.  Also text views can have any type of internal padding they want.  I wouldn't really suggest trying to overdraw a separate view exactly like this, making it work exactly on all OS versions is going to be somewhere between painful and impossible.

Comment: Thank you Gabe for your reply, is there any better way to draw text over images without relying on such calculation ?